# How do I find out what the javadoc error is? ([javadoc] 1 errror, BUILD SUCCESSFUL)

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

When I run my javadoc command with ant or if i try to generate he docs from eclipse (using same build script) this is what I get and  I can't figure out how to find the error. Is there somewhere that I can get more information about the error?
[image: What happens when I run javadoc with ant]

Comment: It says `javadoc: error -- the classpath option may be specified no more than once` on one of the first lines of the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is stated on the third line of the javadoc output:

```
javadoc: error - The -classpath option may be specified no more than once.
```

Your build.xml file specifies -classpath more than once.  To build from multiple classpaths, separate paths by semicolons within one -classpath attribute rather than specifying that attribute multiple times.

Comment: Thanks. 
Eclipse was creating this for me:
classpath="path1; path2; etc" 
And also adding "-classpath" in the addional params.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the javadoc Ant task you are trying to run has two -classpath options specified. It says on the 3rd line of the [javadoc] output.